# Full page NGINX (or Cloudflare) caching and WordPress nonces

Tags: rest-api, nonce, cache

Goal: I want to cache the full WordPress response via NGINX and exclusively use the REST API for the user specific parts.

Issue: I can't get an authenticated nonce to use against the API.

My plan was to expose a rest endpoint that returns a valid nonce shown below:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/nonce', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => function() {
      $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

      $response = [
        'logged_in' => $logged_in,
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
      ];
      return new WP_REST_Response( $response, 200 );
    }
  ) );

  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/auth', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => function() {
      return new WP_REST_Response( [ 'user_id' => get_current_user_id() ], 200 );
    }
  ) );
} );
```

I'd then do an call to the REST endpoint with no nonce to get the unauthenticated nonce.  Then use the unauthenticated nonce to get the authenticated version like so:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    jQuery.get('/wp-json/myplugin/v1/nonce').done(function(res) {
        console.log( 'Got unauthenticated nonce: ' + res.nonce );

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/wp-json/myplugin/v1/nonce',
            method: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', res.nonce );
            },
        }).done( function( res ) {
            console.log( 'Got authenticated nonce: ' + res.nonce );
        } );;

    });

});
```

Then I'd store the authenticated nonce in local storage and use that in conjunction with the `X-WP-Nonce` response header to keep it fresh.  For some reason that doesn't work despite the authentication cookies being passed as part of the request.  What am I missing?

Update: I've found at least two methods to deal with this issue.

1) Skip the `nonce` token altogether by using JWT (for example via the plugin [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)).  No more CSRF but hang on cause XSS comes into the picture.

2) Via NGINX SSI (Server Side Includes).  Basically the only part not cached is the creation of the `nonce` value.  A downside to this approach is if you wanted to use Edge Side Includes (ESI) with your CDN you couldn't.

Note: If I authenticate (send username/password) via a custom REST endpoint I can get a valid authenticated `nonce` at that point but I'm back to square one when that `nonce` expires (the default is 24 hours).

Comment: Are you sure that you're not caching the nonce endpoint too? Keep in mind too that nonces expire, and for authenticated requests you also need a cookie

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  My local environment isn't caching the request at all.  My plan is to refresh the nonce token using the `X-WP-Nonce` HTTP header but I can't get past never getting an "authenticated" nonce.

Comment: so is it the initial nonce that isn't being accepted? You've outlined the flow of execution but you never said which step it failed at

Comment: It fails at the second nonce attempt (the "authenticated" one where I'm passing the nonce as a HTTP header `X-WP-Nonce`) with `{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Cookie nonce is invalid","data":{"status":403}}`